# How do I make multiple async calls in Javascript to update my UI without blocking?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, parallel-processing

I have several dropdownlists on a web page that retrieve their contents via api call to the server, which are all very quick, and an additional call that retrieves 1000 rows from the database - considerably longer response time.  I have this Javascript/Vue code that runs when everything is loaded and ready to go:

```js
setOrderStatuses: async function () {
    ...
},
setSpecialOrders: async function () {
    ...
},
setSubmitterNames: async function () {
    ...
},
...
mounted: function () {
   this.$nextTick(async function () {
      return await Promise.all([
         this.setOrderStatuses(),
         this.setSpecialOrders(),
         this.setSubmitterNames()
      ]);
   });
},
```

...wherein everything retrieves data as expected, but the UI doesn't update until *all* of the promises are fulfilled.  If I put a breakpoint on the server that blocks the answer to `setOrderStatuses()`, for instance, neither of the other methods update the UI until I click `continue` and the promise is filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jus make your mouted method async like :

```
async mounted () {
   await this.setOrderStatuses()
   await this.setSpecialOrders()
   await this.setSubmitterNames()
}
```

Comment: any need for that `this.nextTick()` I had in there?

Comment: not realy need it

Comment: is it work fine ? @ScottBaker

Comment: yep, it works just fine.